# Visual studio 2012 + qt + clang, is it possible?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, clang

Is it actually possible to use Visual Studio as IDE, Qt as framework libraries and clang as internal compiler?

I don't know if that's actually possible but that would ensure I have the best IDE, the best compiler and the best GUI framework

Comment: Is there any link available on how to do it? It may require a bit of "work"

Comment: Best? No. Vs was made to work with its own compiler and would be about as functional in this mode as notepad++

Comment: While some components might not be usable out of the box with a different compiler, you'll certainly get more functionality than Notepad++. All the refactoring, navigation and code completion features will still work.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that the compiler would then support C++11!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible.

AddIn for Visual Studio that integrates Qt:

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23169

AddIn for Visual Studio that allows use of the Clang C/C++ compiler:

https://github.com/ishani/ClangVSx